# Error when increasing the number of hidden layers of DNNRegressor

Tags: python, deep-learning, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I am **successfully** building a DNNRegressor with 2 layers using the following code

```
# Parameters
num_epochs = 1000
STEPS = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 80

#Deep Neural Network Regressor 
feature_column1 = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(train_x)
regressor = learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns = feature_column1, hidden_units= [25,25], model_dir = './output')
regressor.fit(train_x, train_y, max_steps= STEPS, batch_size= BATCH_SIZE)
Ypred = regressor.predict_scores(test_x, as_iterable=True)
Ypred = np.asarray(list(Ypred))
rmse = np.sqrt(((Ypred - test_y) ** 2).mean(axis=0))
print("Root mean square Error: %.3f" %rmse)
```

However, when I try to increase the hidden layers from 2 to 3 by changing `regressor` to `regressor = learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns = feature_column1, hidden_units= [25,25,25], model_dir = './output')`, I keep getting this error message:

> InvalidArgumentError: Shape in shape_and_slice spec [25] does not
>   match the shape stored in checkpoint: [50]     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 =
>   RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

I tried googling this error, but could not see anyone encounter the same problem. Could anyone please help me resolve this problem? I don't understand why I got this error;p

Comment: Have you tried removing your checkpoints and trying again?

Comment: Delete your contents of model_dir and run again.

Comment: @E_net4 and vijay m: thanks a ton! it finally worked out for me!!

Comment: I have added an answer with the suggested fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script appears to load a previously saved model automatically on startup. When you modified the network, the persisted model was no longer compatible with it.

Clearing the saved model output, or using another folder for the model's output, solves this problem.

Comment: @E_net64: Thank you so much!! I got it:)